# The 2nd Owl-carousel slider doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm busy on a site, with 2 photo-sliders from owl-carousel.

The first one works fine, but the second one only shows 1 picture and no buttons and a to big container. new to this so any help would be amazing.

```
        <!-- modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body"> 
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12"> 

                 <!-- portfolio media -->
                 <div class="portfolio-images"> 

                    <!-- image slider -->
                    <div id="owl-portfolio1" class="owl- carousel owl-theme">
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>   
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div> 
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>   
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div> 
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>   
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
                       <div class="item"> <img src="images/print4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>                
                    </div>




                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

                            <script>


                    $(document).ready(function() {

                       $("#owl-portfolio").owl-carousel({
                       });


                       $("#owl-portfolio1").owlcarousel({           
                       });
                    });
        </script>
        </div>








        <div class="col-md-6 work">
              <div class="portfolio-item clearfix"> 

                 <!-- portfolio content -->
                 <div class="portfolio-content pull-right"> <a href="#" class="more-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1"> <i class="fa fa-plus"> </i> </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-content-wrap clearfix">
                       <div class="portfolio-content-center">
                          <h4>x</h4>
                          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.</p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <!-- .portfolio content --> 

                 <!--portfolio image -->
                 <div class="portfolio-image pull-left"> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1"> <img src="images/portfolio-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pull-left" title="" alt="" /> </a> </div>
                 <!-- .portfolio image --> 

              </div>
                 ><!-- .portfolio content --> 

              </div>
           </div>
           <!-- .portfolio item --> 

        </div>
```

Comment: i tried that, if i remove that space, it doesn't show anything anymore

Comment: there is no `#owl-portfolio` in the above code?

Comment: this is the second slider, in the first slider the name is #owl-portfolio, and that one works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#owl-portfolio").owl-carousel({
});


$("#owl-portfolio1").owlcarousel({           
});
```

You're using two different names for the call to owl-carousel. One of these is incorrect, I assume `.owlcarousel()` is the correct one.

**Edit** If this is merely a copy/paste error for Stackoverflow, please let me know.

**Edit 2**

Noticed another odd thing in your carousel (the HTML tag)

```
class="owl- carousel owl-theme"
```

I get a feeling that should be `owl-carousel` rather than separate `owl-` and `carousel` classes.
*Again, if this is a copy/paste error, let me know.*

Comment: alright, but how do i call the second one? this one doesn't seem to work, and i don't know how to get it active.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean. Did changing the function call to the correct name fix it, did it do *something*, or did it have zero effect on the original issue?

Comment: i did nog change the call yet, because i don't understand what i need to call.... i changed it to what is supposed to be.

Comment: Can you not deduce how what the correct way is by looking at the carousel *you yourself confirmed to be working correctly*? Not trying to be sarcastic, but I find it odd to not check what is different between a working version and a broken version, if you already confirm one of two to be working. I only spotted a difference between the two (the function name), which is a likely suspect. However, I can't say for sure if you won't test it.

Comment: i did test it, i coppied the whole carousel of the first one, and changed it to where i supposed to get the pictures from, i finds te pictures but it doens't finds the photoslider, that is what my problem is.

Comment: Please re-read what I posted. I never said the issue was in your HTML, but in your **function call**.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm just a student in his 2th year, + i get lessons in dutch so i don't even know what that is.

Comment: (Note: this is a Dutch translation of my original answer. You're not missing anything if you don't know what this says) Dan heb je geluk :) De function call is letterlijk het gebruik van de functie `$("#elementID").owlcarousel()` (let even niet op het `#elementID`, dat moet gewoon het correcte ID van je carousel zijn), waarmee je de plugin toepast op je element. De eerste keer gebruik je `.owlcarousel()`, de tweede keer `.owl-carousel()`. Waarschijnlijk bestaat er maar een van de twee, ik denk dat dat koppelteken daar gewoon weg moet.

Comment: (Still re-explaining in Dutch, you're not missing anything) En in geval van edit2 denk ik dat je de spatie tussen `owl-` en `carousel` moet weghalen. Alles wat gescheiden wordt door spaties wordt in je HTML opgepikt als verschillende classes. Nu heeft je object de classes `owl-`, `carousel` en `owl-theme`. Als je die spatie weghaalt heb je de classes `owl-carousel` en `owl-theme`. Dat lijkt me logischer :)

Comment: haha kijk eens aan :) wat het is, de eerste carousel deed het al zonder dat ik die function call erin had zitten, nu ik hem erin heb staan *zonder verschillen* werkt hij alsnog niet, en de eerste nog steeds wel. en hierdoor liep ik vast, omdat ik het gewoon niet meer snapte.

Comment: Ik heb net de homepage van owl carousel nagekeken: `class="owl-carousel"` moet je erin zetten (dus corrigeren zoals ik zei, spatie weghalen) en je function call is `$("#owl-example").owlCarousel();` (met jouw ID dan, en let op die hoofdletter! Functienamen zijn case sensitive). Dan zou het moeten werken.

Comment: ik heb het geprobeerd veranderd nog steeds niks, boven in heb ik ook het stuk neergezet waar wat voor de knop nodig is, misschien vind je daar wat in?